# What is the area of $ABCD$ parallelogram where $E$ is mid-point of BC and the area of $BEC$ is 126?

Tags: geometry, contest-math, triangles, area

[image]

> $ABCD$ is a parallelogram. Point $E$ divides $BC$ into two equal
>   lengths. If the area of $BEF$ is **126**, what is the area of $ABCD$?

**Source: Bangladesh Math Olympiad 2017 Junior Category.**

I can not solve this problem. I am confused on the position of $'F'$. There is no information mentioned about it. Is there any lack of information in this question? Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: The area of $BEF$ doesn't depend on the position of $F\in AD$ because it is equal $\frac{BE\cdot h}{2}$ where $h$ is the height of the parallelogram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

1. Consider the area of $\triangle BFC$, which shares the same height with $\triangle BEF$.
2. Draw an auxiliary line through $F$ parallel to $AB$ to see that the area found in step (1) is actually half of the area of the parallelogram $ABCD$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: CEF has the same area as BEF as they are both a half of the same parallelogram.

Answer (score 2):

Let $FK$ be an altitude of $ABCD$.

Thus,
$$S_{ABCD}=BC\cdot FK=2BE\cdot FK=4\cdot\frac{BE\cdot FK}{2}=4\cdot126=504.$$